# I want to use Youtube's API and have access to my channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm completely new to using APIs, and I'm feeling lost when it comes to using code to access my YouTube account. I managed to get the API key, but now I'm confused over this OAuth thing. Can anyone help me and explain how I can tackle OAuth 2 for the YouTube API?

all this OAuth 2 stuff is confusing me. I want to be able to access my YouTube account programmatically, but I'm not sure where to start with OAuth 2 authentication and authorization.Im using java

Comment: Try with your apikey. It's simpler, do not mix the two things

Comment: @pierpy isn't just using the API key only able to access public data? I want to code something that can change something in my account and I need Oauth2 for that

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I didn’t notice that, you have to deal with OAuth